# Magento add tabs to custom module show content in left side

Tags: module, tabs

[image]

Like you can see in the picture, in my custom module I am trying to create edit action with tabs, but I cannot make it right.
Here is my code :

**Form : **

```
class .._Block_Adminhtml_Slide_Edit_Form
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        // instantiate a new form to display our brand for editing
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl(
                '.._admin/slide/edit', 
                array(
                    '_current' => true,
                    'continue' => 0,
                )
            ),
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ));
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

**and last one : `form.php` (inside Tab folder)**

```
class Iwp_Slideshow_Block_Adminhtml_Slide_Edit_Tab_Form
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
{
    ... return $this;
}
```

**Solved!**

The problem was that I created the form twice, first in `edit->form.php` and second in `edit->tab->form.php` with the same `id`. So I had `js` error in the admin area.

Comment: You should answer for others following this question.